# CKUserIdentity userRecordID property is an optional. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

The **CKUserIdentity** class has a property named **userRecordID** of type **CKRecord.ID?**

Why is **userRecordID** an optional? Surely it will never be nil?

Comment: IF your user doesn't have an appleID or indeed isn't logged in with one then I think it will be nil.

Comment: If it is nil what should I do?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? No idea what you should do? In what context? Ignore it? Pop up an error message?

Comment: An identity exists for the user in the database. But the identity has no record so it...doesn't exist in the database? Wait, the user exist or doesn't exist?.Choose whatever context you like. What do I do? If I ignore it then what have I achieved fetching this thing? If I pop up an error message, what should it say?

Comment: Tell him to login with his appleID if he wants to use your app cause it won't work without it.

Comment: There's a boolean on the class called 'hasiCloudAccount' so that will do